# Print array errors

Tags: java

I am trying to print an array and I think I got all the codes correct, don't known why I am getting the result below...
my code is

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[8];

        for (int i = 0; i< array.length; i++){
            array[i] = i;
            System.out.print("| " + array + " ");
        }

        System.out.println(" ");
    }
}
```

but i am printing result like below, why?

| [I@15db9742 | [I@15db9742 | [I@15db9742 | [I@15db9742 | [I@15db9742 | [I@15db9742 | [I@15db9742 | [I@15db9742

Comment: Change `array` to `array[i]` in `System.out.print("| " + array + " ");`.

Comment: Try `array[i]` instead of `array`.

Comment: You have to print the elements of the arrays separately. You see the internal reference of the array.

Comment: Thanks guys, it works

Answer (score 6):

It's because

`System.out.print("| " + array + " ");`

is shorthand for

`System.out.print("| " + array.toString() + " ");`

and the `toString()` method doesn't print the individual elements (if it did then all hell could be let loose for large arrays, so the clever Java bods decided to delegate that to `Arrays.toString(array)`).

What you need in this case is

`System.out.print("| " + array[i] + " ");`

Comment: Even if `array.toString()` printed out every element, the original code still wouldn't behave as intended. It would repeatedly print out the entire array, rather than once.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the **@15db9742**, that is the hashcode of the array object.

try with:

```
for (int i = 0; i< array.length; i++){
    array[i] = i;
    System.out.print("| " + array[i]+ " ");
}
```

or printing all at once

```
Arrays.toString(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's printing exactly what you have instructed it to do so, what output are you expecting?

What values are in the original Array etc?

Try printing the chosen array item instead of the whole array.

public static void main(String[] args) {
int[] array = new int[8];

```
for (int i = 0; i< array.length; i++){
var item = array[i];
System.out.print("| " + item + " ");
}
System.out.println(" ");
```